Finding the coordinates between 2 non intersecting curves with the minimum distance
Find the coordinates of the point on the parabola $y^2 = 8x$ which is at a minimum distance from the circle $x^2 + (y+6)^2 = 1$
my approach:
if P and Q are points on the parabola and circle respectively, such that distance between P and Q is minimum, the line connecting P and Q should be normal to the 2 curves, meaning the tangent of parabola at P and the tangent of the circle at Q should be parallel (since tangents are perpendicular to Normals), meaning their derivatives(gradients) should be equal.
implicitly differentiating the 2 curves,
$$y^{2}=8x, \frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{4}{y}$$
$$x^{2}+\left(y+6\right)^{2}=1, \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y+6}$$
$$\frac{4}{y} = -\frac{x}{y+6} \\
y=-\frac{24}{x+4}$$
that curve should connect the points which are cloeset to the parabola and the circle

it also does look close, so by equating the green graph to the parabola we can get the coordinate of P as $(2,-4)$
but the issue it, since the derivatives are equal, since the lines are parallel, the Normals must equal too (because both Normals are the same line), meaning the gradient of the normal must equal to each other
using $m_1 m_2 =-1$
$\frac{4}{y}=-\frac{x}{y+6}$ can be written as $-\frac{4}{y}=\frac{y+6}{x}$

but this gives the purple curve as above, which does intersect the parabola in the same point at P, but connect the circle at 2 different point, does that mean that there are 2 Q points? or am i missing something?

You cannot simply set the two derivatives equal to each other, since you are evaluating the derivatives at 2 different points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$.

i see why that could be a problem, but why did i get the right answer though?

You are overcomplicating things. I will go over a much simpler method of getting the answer, but first: your method fails because you need to take the derivative of the two curves at their respective points. What this means is, wherever the two points end up being, let's call the one on the parabola $(x_1, y_1)$ and the point on the circle $(x_2, y_2)$. Then yes, if we take the derivatives of the curve and plug in at the points on each curve, the slopes should be equal. This means $\frac{4}{y_1} = \frac{-x_2}{y_2+6}$. Now, while this is technically correct, I can't see an appealing way to go about solving this problem from here. However, there is a much easier way to do this.
Notice that, when you are dealing with circles, minimizing the distance between a point on a circle and a point on some other curve is the same as minimizing the distance between the center of the circle and some point on a curve. This is because, since the line with both points on them is perpendicular to both curves, and hence perpendicular to the circle, it will pass straight through the center. 
Hopefully the image makes it clear why this is the case.
Now, solving the problem of minimizing the distance from some point $(x,y)$ on the parabola and the point $(0,-6)$ is much easier. We can write the slope of the line as $\frac{y+6}{x}$ and write the derivative of the parabola calculated at the point as $\frac{4}{y}$. Since these should be perpendicular, their product is $-1$ and so $\frac{y+6}{x} = -\frac{y}{4}$. We can do some substitutions and solving, and you are left with a very convenient answer of $(2,-4)$ as shown on the graph above.

but isnt it the same formula gained from equating the derivatives? thus the same method to finding the coordinates? $\frac{4}{y}=-\frac{x}{y+6}$ is same as $\frac{y+6}{x}=-\frac{y}{4}$ to get the coordinates of the point on the parabola we can use either of those 2 equations (since both are the same) and $y^{2}=8x$ by both methods we get the same answer

@ChinthanaNadun Yes, technically both methods are the same, and they do both arrive at the correct answer, as the intersection on the parabola is at the same point. However, the idea is to understand that the only thing that matters graphically is where the $\frac{y+6}{x}=-\frac{y}{4}$ curve intersects the parabola. What this represents is the solution for the closest point on the parabola, not necessarily the path of shortest distance. So, the intersection of these curves and the circle is meaningless, and also why your two curves did not intersect the circle at the same spot.

oh, i see how i overcomplicated things, went too far from the question, thank you for pointing that out
